# Batch update multiple PDFs meta data

Tags: pdf, batch, pdfcreator

I Need to update a lot of old PDFs with newer meta data (File > Properties> Description - Title, Author, Subject...)

I have too many to do it manually and could nto find a way to apply the same meta data to multiple pdf files.

Does anyone have any ideas for this? If it cant be done with Adobe Acrobat Pro then please suggest a tool that may be able to do batch renames/meta data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a tool like [AutoMetadata](https://www.evermap.com/autometadata.asp)

It'll give you the ability to change all metadata in one click.

Just download and install it, then open it. 
On the AutoMetadata window, click on Select Files, then select all files you need to change their metadata and click Open. Now you'll see them on the program, just select them all and go to Edit menu, and choose Set Properties For Selected Recordes and a new dailog will open. Now, you can just check on the overwrite option that you want to overwrite it in all documents then click OK.

And you're done !

Comment: Amazing, this software is awesome and free! I need to remedy my google searching skills because I could not find anything remotely as good as this.  Thanks!